# How to build cmake 3.1.3 using clang 3.6.0 and libc++?

Tags: compilation, cmake, clang, libc++

I'm trying to build cmake 3.1.3 using clang and its own c++ library, i.e:

```
export CC=clang 
export CXX=clang++ 
export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" 
export LDFLAGS="-lc++ -lc++abi"
```

followed by

```
./bootstrap
```

However, this does not work due to the way the bootstrap script tests the CXX compiler. If I hack the bootstrap file and add the LDFLAGS to the CXX test I can start to compile cmake. However, once I reach the bootstrap stage, the compile cmake binary is broken. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use a different CMake build instead of the bootstrap process?

Comment: I can try, which one would you recommend?

Comment: Just about anything. You could bootstrap one with GCC if you have no other option. My point was that the bootstrap process is only necessary if you have no prior CMake. If you can't make the bootstrap work with Clang, why not use an actual CMake instead?

Comment: So I tried using the existing cmake installation and I can get a bit farther with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Angew's idea and trying to compile with the existing cmake installation actually gets you a bit farther: If you use almost the same exports as above:

```
export CC=clang 
export CXX=clang++ 
export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" 
export LDFLAGS="-L${COMPILERROOT}/lib -lc++ -lc++abi"
```

and a little sed to get around a weird compilation error (assuming you are in a different build directory and you extracted the cmake sources to the directory ../cmake from the current one)

```
sed -i s/kwsys_ios::hex/cmsys_ios::istringstream::hex/g ../cmake/Source/kwsys/SystemInformation.cxx
sed -i s/kwsys_ios::dec/cmsys_ios::istringstream::dec/g ../cmake/Source/kwsys/SystemInformation.cxx
```

You can then compile cmake via:

```
cmake ../cmake/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALLDIR}
make -j${NPROC}
make install
```

It still crashed for example if I try to cmake a Cern ROOT6 install:

```
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
uncaught_exception not yet implemented

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6e495e9 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6e495e9 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6e4acf8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b755a5 in std::uncaught_exception() () from /home/balzer/middleware/software/clang/3.6.0/lib/libc++.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff7ba80fd in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry() () from /home/balzer/middleware/software/clang/3.6.0/lib/libc++.so.1
#4  0x0000000000531561 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) ()
#5  0x0000000000530c8c in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) ()
#6  0x000000000052fccb in cmakemainMessageCallback(char const*, char const*, bool&, void*) ()
#7  0x00000000007527c9 in cmSystemTools::Message(char const*, char const*) ()
#8  0x000000000085c934 in cmake::IssueMessage(cmake::MessageType, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cmListFileBacktrace const&) ()
#9  0x000000000062a756 in cmMakefile::IssueMessage(cmake::MessageType, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const ()
#10 0x00000000009c56cb in cmConditionEvaluator::GetDefinitionIfUnquoted(cmExpandedCommandArgument const&) const ()
#11 0x00000000009c57fd in cmConditionEvaluator::GetVariableOrString(cmExpandedCommandArgument const&) const ()
#12 0x00000000009c0600 in cmConditionEvaluator::HandleLevel2(std::__1::list<cmExpandedCommandArgument, std::__1::allocator<cmExpandedCommandArgument> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, cmake::MessageType&) ()
#13 0x00000000009bce3b in cmConditionEvaluator::IsTrue(std::__1::vector<cmExpandedCommandArgument, std::__1::allocator<cmExpandedCommandArgument> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, cmake::MessageType&) ()
#14 0x00000000009bdd5e in cmConditionEvaluator::HandleLevel0(std::__1::list<cmExpandedCommandArgument, std::__1::allocator<cmExpandedCommandArgument> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, cmake::MessageType&) ()
#15 0x00000000009bcd91 in cmConditionEvaluator::IsTrue(std::__1::vector<cmExpandedCommandArgument, std::__1::allocator<cmExpandedCommandArgument> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, cmake::MessageType&) ()
#16 0x00000000009d902b in cmIfCommand::InvokeInitialPass(std::__1::vector<cmListFileArgument, std::__1::allocator<cmListFileArgument> > const&, cmExecutionStatus&) ()
#17 0x000000000062b4d6 in cmMakefile::ExecuteCommand(cmListFileFunction const&, cmExecutionStatus&) ()
#18 0x000000000098ffb1 in cmForEachFunctionBlocker::IsFunctionBlocked(cmListFileFunction const&, cmMakefile&, cmExecutionStatus&) ()
#19 0x000000000062c5cb in cmMakefile::IsFunctionBlocked(cmListFileFunction const&, cmExecutionStatus&) ()
#20 0x000000000062b21c in cmMakefile::ExecuteCommand(cmListFileFunction const&, cmExecutionStatus&) ()
#21 0x0000000000630242 in cmMakefile::ReadListFile(char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, bool) ()
#22 0x00000000005cbad4 in cmLocalGenerator::ReadInputFile() ()
#23 0x00000000005cb437 in cmLocalGenerator::Configure() ()
#24 0x0000000000ca2af8 in cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3::Configure() ()
#25 0x0000000000bf3df6 in cmGlobalGenerator::Configure() ()
#26 0x0000000000c44edd in cmGlobalUnixMakefileGenerator3::Configure() ()
#27 0x000000000084c49e in cmake::ActualConfigure() ()
#28 0x0000000000849b24 in cmake::Configure() ()
#29 0x0000000000850efa in cmake::Run(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) ()
#30 0x000000000052f665 in do_cmake(int, char const* const*) ()
#31 0x000000000052c149 in main ()
```

However, if I add the -Wno-dev option to the cmake call it works fine.